# What's the equivalent of a C++ template in Visual Basic.NET?

Tags: c++, vb.net, templates, generics

Does VB.NET provide a way to define the equivalent to a C++ template, such as a function template or a class template?

If so, does template specialization work the same way, and provide the same behaviors?

Or are templates a C++ operation that cannot be perfectly translated into VB.NET?

Comment: Some template things can be translated quite roughly into VB.net. Quite a few more template things don't have any real analog in VB.net at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET doesn't provide any kind of metaprogramming built into the language. Like the rest of the .Net languages, your main tool is type generics. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx

You can emulate certain aspects of C++ templates by using the T4 text generation system that will allow you to have arbitrarily complex code generation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478.aspx